# AngularJs and a socket server

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, sockets

I am about to set my `node.js / socket.io` server up but since this is my first time using angular, I have a few questions.

Q: Are there any modules available with angular that makes socket connection / communication easier or would I have to build my own module?

Q: Is there something I should be aware about when making the socket server because of angular's `two way databinding`?

I have been reading up on blogs building a simple chat application using Angular and Node however I am looking for a more global use of a socket since it is going to be used on every page in my application.

Comment: `AngularJS` is a frontend based application and very good for single page applications. `node.js` is a backend based application. Interacting with socket.io is not a good way to handle a interface (keep your environments atomar). What about HTTP & RESTful?

Comment: @lin This is purely for chat  and other instant messaging like functions. i already have a Node RESTful api running that runs my database connection calls'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Sure

There is kinda well known and popular [library](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io) from @btford. You just need to include the library into your project and make a factory that returns you helpers like `addListener`,  `removeListener`,  `removeAllListeners`,  `emit`.. for your project.

```
angular.module('myApp', [
  'btford.socket-io',
  'myApp.MyCtrl'
]).
factory('mySocket', function (socketFactory) {
  return socketFactory();
});
```

### Sample

There is also a nice webtutorial on [HTML5 Rocks](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/frameworks/angular-websockets/) where is built a simple app with Node.js (Express) and Angular.js and they communicate between each other via Socket.io in both directions. Sources are available on [Github](https://github.com/btford/angular-socket-io-im).

### Basics (sample from [tutsplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/more-responsive-single-page-applications-with-angularjs-socketio-creating-the-library--cms-21738))

Basically, just make a simple Node.js listener with callback:

```
var io = require('socket.io')(8080);

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('echo', function (data) {
        socket.emit('echo', data);
    });

    socket.on('echo-ack', function (data, callback) {
        callback(data);
    });
});
```

.. include the scripts to your frontend app ..

```
<script src="'angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script src="angular-socket.js"></script>
<div ng-controller="Ctrl">
    <input ng-model="dataToSend">
    <button ng-click="emitBasic()">Send</button>
    <button ng-click="emitACK()">Send (ACK)</button>
    <div>Server Response: {{ serverResponse }}</div>
    <div>Server Response (ACK): {{ serverResponseACK }}</div>
</div>
```

.. include the module ..

```
var module = angular.module('socket.io', []);



app.controller('Ctrl', function Ctrl($scope, $socket) {
   $socket.on('echo', function (data) {
      $scope.serverResponse = data;
   });
   // ………
});
```

Answer (score 1):

> Are there any modules available with angular that makes socket connection / communication easier or would i have to build my own module?

Not sure what modules you could use but whatever you use, encapsulate it into it's own service so that the data access is cleanly separated from application logic and UI

> is there something I should be aware about when making the socket server because of angular's two way databinding?

As long as you do the aboce, you've nothing to worry about two way binding. In your controllers (which bind the scope to the view), use the service to get data and update scope to correctly update UI.